# void android.view.View.setVisibility(int) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, view, void

i searched every directory and i dont see problem, please help me.

> BlockquoteProcess:
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.projectmanagement.wallet.CreateCashActivity.setViewOrUpdateWallet(CreateCashActivity.java:58)
> at com.example.projectmanagement.wallet.CreateCashActivity.onCreate(CreateCashActivity.java:46)

And my code:

public class CreateCashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText inputWalletTitle, inputWalletSubtitle, inputWalletText;

private Wallet alreadyAvailableWallet;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_wallet);

    ImageView imageBack = findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
    imageBack.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

    inputWalletTitle = findViewById(R.id.inputWalletTitle);
    inputWalletSubtitle = findViewById(R.id.inputWalletSubtitle);
    inputWalletText = findViewById(R.id.inputWalletText);

    Button save_btn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    save_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> saveWallet());

    ImageView imageSave = findViewById(R.id.imageSave);
    imageSave.setOnClickListener(v -> saveWallet());

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isViewOrUpdate", false)) {
        alreadyAvailableWallet = (Wallet) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("wallet");
        setViewOrUpdateWallet();
    }

}

private void setViewOrUpdateWallet() {
    inputWalletTitle.setText(alreadyAvailableWallet.getTitle());
    inputWalletSubtitle.setText(alreadyAvailableWallet.getSubtitle());
    inputWalletText.setText(alreadyAvailableWallet.getWalletText());


    if (alreadyAvailableWallet != null) {
        this.findViewById(R.id.layoutDeleteWallet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


private void saveWallet() {
    if (inputWalletTitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Uzupełnij kwotę oraz walutę!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (inputWalletSubtitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Brak zlecenia!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (inputWalletText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Brak opisu wydatku!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    final Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
    wallet.setTitle(inputWalletTitle.getText().toString());
    wallet.setSubtitle(inputWalletSubtitle.getText().toString());
    wallet.setWalletText(inputWalletText.getText().toString());


    if (alreadyAvailableWallet != null) {
        wallet.setId(alreadyAvailableWallet.getId());
    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class SaveWalletTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            WalletDatabase.getDatebase(getApplicationContext()).walletDao().insertWallet(wallet);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    new SaveWalletTask().execute();

}

public void deleteText(View view) {
    final LinearLayout layoutMiscellcash = findViewById(R.id.layoutDeleteWallet);


    layoutMiscellcash.findViewById(R.id.layoutDeleteWallet).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
            class DeleteWalletTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    WalletDatabase.getDatebase(getApplicationContext()).walletDao()
                            .deleteWallet(alreadyAvailableWallet);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("isWalletDeleted", true);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            new DeleteWalletTask().execute();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {


        }
    }
}
```

}

Logcat show line 58 and 46, this is:

`this.findViewById(R.id.layoutDeleteWallet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

and:
`if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isViewOrUpdate", false)) { alreadyAvailableWallet = (Wallet) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("wallet"); setViewOrUpdateWallet(); }`

I dont see problem in this. Please help.

Comment: Can we see the xml? But essentially it seems it can't find the item in the inflated `activity_create_wallet.xml` for that view

Comment: Most probably the id `layoutDeleteWallet` doesn't exist in the layout

Comment: U have  right guys.. It was problem in activity_create_wallet in layoutDeleteWallet... i used wrong layout name.. i writed 'layoutDelete' without word 'Wallet' and that's it.. Thank u so much. I checked my project long time..